# Matlab coder causing problems with matrix expansion in bsxfun

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, mex, bsxfun

I've been trying to vectorize some operations from code a bachelor student wrote for us. He used ugly nested loops which I tried to change into bsxfun calls. This works when I use this function as is, but when I try to mex compile it using coder, I get an error.

Edit: I realize I should clarify some parts of the code. S, W, and N are nxn matrices that indicate preference of a pairwise comparison ij. mu is a row vector containing the (predicted) scores of the absolute rating reconstruction.

To check what the code does, you might wanna check the very bottom of the page.

The original code reads as follows:

```
for i = 1:n
    for j = i:n
        if i~= j
            mu = x(i) - x(j);
            md1 = normcdf(-delta1, mu); %minus d0
            md0 = normcdf(-delta0, mu);
            d0 = normcdf( delta0, mu);
            d1 = normcdf( delta1, mu);

            Y = Y + S(i,j) .* log(1  - d1) + ...
                    W(i,j) .* log(d1 - d0) + ...
                    N(i,j) .* log(d0 - md0) + ...
                    W(j,i) .* log(md0 - md1) + ...
                    S(j,i) .* log(md1);

        end
    end
end
Y = -Y; %this will be used in fminsearch, therefore the negative sign
```

I wrote a quick and dirty vectorized solution for this:

```
diffs = bsxfun(@minus,x,x');

% create the deltas array augmented by -Inf and Inf for easy diff calculation
deltass = sort([-Inf, Inf, deltas, -1*deltas]);
deltass = reshape(deltass, [1, 1, length(deltass)]);
normcdfs = diff(1-bsxfun(@normcdfupper, diffs, deltass), 1, 3);
normcdfs(repmat(logical(tril(ones(size(normcdfs(:,:,1))))),[1,1,length(deltass)-1])) = 1;

Y = -sum(sum(sum(normcdfs_input.*log(normcdfs))));
```

Edit: normcdfupper is a wrapper class I wrote that calls normcdf(diff, delta, 'upper') since I was running into the problem, that tail ends could cause an error.

Now like I said, this works fine in my day to day use. But since mexing the old nested for loop version brought an immense speedup, I tried doing the same with this sped up version, only to encounter the following error in coder:

```
Expansion is only supported along dimensions where one input argument or the other has a fixed length of 1.

Error in lik_ml (line 27)
normcdfs = diff(1-bsxfun(@normcdfupper,diffs,deltass),1,3);
```

diffs is a :infx:inf double, and deltass is a 1x1x:inf double. Coder tells me so:

[diffs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAJVa.png)
[deltass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKTzl.png)

If anyone could help me out with this error message, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit: Some code to test it on:

```
clear all;

% rng(322);
delta0 = 1;
delta1 = 2;
deltas = [delta0, delta1];

sigma = 0.5;
options = 5;

maxVotes = 10000;
voteStep = 3;

initialVoteStep = 3;

raw_mu = rand(1,options);
mu = sort(zscore(raw_mu));

S = zeros(options);
W = zeros(options);
N = zeros(options);

for i = 1:options
    for j = i:options
        if i ~= j
            S(i,j) = 1 - normcdf(delta1, mu(i)-mu(j));
            W(i,j) = normcdf( delta1, mu(i)-mu(j)) - normcdf( delta0, mu(i)-mu(j));
            N(i,j) = normcdf( delta0, mu(i)-mu(j)) - normcdf(-delta0, mu(i)-mu(j));
            W(j,i) = normcdf(-delta0, mu(i)-mu(j)) - normcdf(-delta1, mu(i)-mu(j));
            S(j,i) = normcdf(-delta1, mu(i)-mu(j));
        end
    end
end

diffs = bsxfun(@minus,mu,mu');
deltass = sort([-Inf, Inf, deltas, -1*deltas]);
deltass = reshape(deltass,[1,1,length(deltass)]);
normcdfs = diff(bsxfun(@(x,y) normcdf(y,x),diffs,deltass),1,3);
```

Comment: Where do you define `x`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I modified the code slightly. x was meant to be mu. I will edit the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version of for loop

```
[I,J] = meshgrid(1:n);
idx = I<J;
I = I(idx);
J = J(idx);
IJ = sub2ind([n n],I,J);
JI = sub2ind([n n],J,I);
mu = x(I)-x(J);
md1 = normcdf(-delta1, mu).'; 
md0 = normcdf(-delta0, mu).';
d0 = normcdf( delta0, mu).';
d1 = normcdf( delta1, mu).';
Y = sum(S(IJ) .* log(max(0,1  - d1)) + ...
W(IJ) .* log(max(0,d1 - d0)) + ...
N(IJ) .* log(max(0,d0 - md0)) + ...
W(JI) .* log(max(0,md0 - md1)) + ...
S(JI) .* log(max(0,md1)));
```

Comment: There are some problems with your code. First of all, there is a matrix mulitplication error:

`size(S(IJ))

    ans =

        20     1

    size(log(1-d1))

    ans =

        1     20`

so I changed the dimensions of the normcdfs to be transposed. But then the results differ. With rng(322) for the code snippet at the bottom of my original post and feeding the respective variables into your and the original solution:

`lik5_ml_delta_known(mu,S,W,N,delta0,delta1) ans =

   10.3631
lik5_ml_delta_known3(mu,S,W,N,delta0,delta1) ans =

   17.6042`

:(

Comment: Additionally, the real issue I am having is understanding why my implementation cannot be mexed. The error message that is given doesn't provide enough for me to understand it.

Comment: @FranzHahn vectorized version is correct except one traspose should be applied that you mentioned.results are different because in loop version vs vectorized version random numbers are differently generated. in vectorized version the first 20 random numbers is stored in `md1` but in loop version the first 4 random numbers stored in `md1` `md0` `d0` `d1` then second 4 numbers ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be blind, but I don't see how random numbers take an effect here. We are simply calculating the log likelihood of the data (S/W/N matrices) given the model (Normal distribution with means mu). There is no call to a random number generator in the calculation, it merely happens in the data generation, and I am putting in the exact same variables.

Comment: I believe the error in your implementation lies in the fact that the original doubly nested for loop runs from i=1:options, and j=**i**:options. This seems to be not considered in your implementation.

Comment: @FranzHahn sorry answer updated. I assumed that nested loop is `for j = 1:n` instead of  `for j = i:n`

Comment: Thanks, I was just fiddling around with it and found that this produces the correct results. I will give this a shot, and upvote your answer, but I am still looking for a solution to my problem regarding the mex compilation error.

Comment: Your implementation is actually faster than my bsxfun implementation, and I was able to mex both yours and my bsxfun eventually. Yours is faster in the mexed case as well. Thank you very much. Accepted your solution!

Comment: Glad if it can help